# Forwarding port to a VM - How to?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, port, forwarding

I use Win 8 Ent x64 on my PC, and I also have a Win 7 VMware virtual machine set up using a bridged network adapter.

The IPv4 number for the Win 7 VM is 192.168.1.115.

I require access to the VM from the Internet through port 1688.

How do I set up port forwarding to achieve this?

My router is a Cisco Linksys WAG120N.

=========

If you require any further information to help me with this, I will gladly supply it.

=========

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a bridged network adaptor, the VM has its own IP address on your lan, the same way a physical system would. Just set up a port forward to that ip address and port on your router as per normal